# Cant understand how we got this equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation, spline

I was going through a tutorial that introduces cubic splines. A snapshot of the tutorial is as follows :

Image begins:

[image]

Image End:

Now I dont understand how we got:

$y_1''=6a_1(x_1-x_1)+2b_1=0 + 2b_1=2b1$

I dont understand how

$6a_1(x_1-x_1)+2b_1=0 + 2b_1$ or how $6a_1(x_1-x_1)=0$

Any help on how we got this would be appreciated:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the segment where $x_1 \le x \le x_2$, we have
$$
y''(x) = 6a_1(x-x_1) + 2b_1
$$
We want to impose the constraint that $y''(x_1)$ is equal to some given number $y''_1$.
Then
$$
y''_1 = y''(x_1)   \Longrightarrow y''_1 = 6a_1(x_1-x_1) + 2b_1
$$
But $6a_1(x_1-x_1) = 6a_1 \times 0 = 0$, so we get
$$
y''_1 = 0 + 2b_1 = 2b_1
$$